# How to track changes to user groups and permissions in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

According to the requirements of information security, it is necessary to track changes in user groups and permissions in the Django admin panel! Using signals I catch creation and deletion of the user. How can I track changes in user fields, changes in his groups and permissions?

[image]

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from app.utils import write_message_to_logger

user = get_user_model()

@receiver(post_save, sender=user)
def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        write_message_to_logger('Created new user')


@receiver(post_delete, sender=user)
def delete_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    write_message_to_logger('User was deleted')
```

I will be grateful for the answer

Signal **post_save** on creation and change of the user has no information, necessary for me.
The **instance.get_group_permissions()** method gives information about existing groups, not about those currently assigned.